# navbar not 100% width when browser is resized bootstrap 3.5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar in which the width does not fit 100% when the browser is resized less than 760px [image: resized less than 760px]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" style="margin-bottom:0;">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="#">
            </a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" style="height: 1px;">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li class="hidden"><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>

                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Signup</a></li>
                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                <li>
                    <form action="#">
                        <a href="#">Request</a>
                    </form>
                </li>
                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                <li><a target="_blank" href="#"></a></li>


            </ul>

        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Here are some custom css i used

```
@media (min-width: 760px) {
    .container {
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        width: auto
    }
}
```

Comment: I reproduced your navigation with bootstrap 3.5 and I can't see the problem. Maybe it's happening because of something else. Could you please provide a link to your website to see the actual problem?

Comment: check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/oghenes/u27r6dL2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 760px){
    .container {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.container-fluid>.navbar-collapse, .container-fluid>.navbar-header, .container>.navbar-collapse, .container>.navbar-header {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Here is a fiddle for it https://jsfiddle.net/u27r6dL2/3/

Comment: I've edited my post so you can add the CSS from my post and it should work perfectly.

Comment: hello, thanks but it is still there. I have added the body og the page https://jsfiddle.net/oghenes/u27r6dL2/13/